# How to delete a file from /var/tmp (centos 7)

Tags: linux, centos, rm

I have a file, that gets created when a task is ready to run. My script needs to complete this task and at the end of the successful completion, it needs to delete this file.

File get created by one of about 20-25 users, all belonging to the same group.

My service account has the same group as its default group

File permissions are as such

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 scuser07 sec_ops 47 Jan 14 19:17 /var/tmp/sc_req
```

and /var/tmp permissions are as follows

```
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root 4096 Jan 14 20:00 /var/tmp
```

yet, I can not delete the sc_req file when my script successfully exits

Comment: Does the service account own the files that it's trying to delete?

Comment: No. account which needs to delete the file is a control service accout but it has the same default group, i.e. sec_ops.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? What is the output of `ausearch -m avc -ts today -i` (given that you've run your script today).

Answer (score 2):

```
drwxrwxrwt. 4 root root 4096 Jan 14 20:00 /var/tmp
```

The `t`instead of the last `x` in the permission letters means the directory has the *sticky bit* set, which is normal for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. It causes an additional restriction in that directory: you will be able to delete a file *only if you are the owner of that file.*

The purpose of this is to prevent users from sabotaging each other's work by deleting other users' temporary files.

Comment: Note however, the solution to you problem is not to remove the `t`. That will cause more problems. The solution is to not change user. Or create another `tmp` for task.